# Getting the row count until the highest date from pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have df like below I want to create dayshigh column. This column will show the  row counts until the highest date.

```
date        high
05-06-20    1.85
08-06-20    1.88
09-06-20    2
10-06-20    2.11
11-06-20    2.21
12-06-20    2.17
15-06-20    1.99
16-06-20    2.15
17-06-20    16
18-06-20    9
19-06-20    14.67
```

should be like:

```
date        high    dayshigh
05-06-20    1.85    nan
08-06-20    1.88    1
09-06-20    2       2
10-06-20    2.11    3
11-06-20    2.21    4
12-06-20    2.17    0
15-06-20    1.99    0
16-06-20    2.15    1
17-06-20    16      8
18-06-20    9       0
19-06-20    14.67   1
```

using the below code but showing error somehow:

```
df["DaysHigh"] = np.repeat(0, len(df))
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    for j in range(df["DaysHigh"][i].index, len(df)):
        if df["high"][i] > df["high"][i-1]:
            df["DaysHigh"][i] = df["DaysHigh"][i-1] + 1
        else:
            df["DaysHigh"][i] = 0
```

At which point am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: How did you get 8 in row 17-06-20

Comment: 17-06-20 is 16 so it is bigger than the previous 8 row values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I did, here is my solution:

```
df["DaysHigh"] = np.repeat(0, len(df))
for i in range(0, len(df)):
#for i in range(len(df)-1000, len(df)): 
    for j in reversed(range(i)):
        if df["high"][i] > df["high"][j]:
            df["DaysHigh"][i] = df["DaysHigh"][i] + 1
        else:
            break

print(df)
date        high    dayshigh
05-06-20    1.85    nan
08-06-20    1.88    1
09-06-20    2.00    2
10-06-20    2.11    3
11-06-20    2.21    4
12-06-20    2.17    0
15-06-20    1.99    0
16-06-20    2.15    1
17-06-20    16.00   8
18-06-20    9.00    0
19-06-20    14.67   1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the dayshigh number for 17-06-20 supposed to be 2 instead of 8? If so, you can basically use the code you had already written here. There are three changes I'm making below:

1. starting i from 1 instead of 0 to avoid trying to access the -1th element
2. removing the loop over j (doesn't seem to be necessary)
3. using loc to set the values instead of df["high"][i] -- you'll see this should resolve the warnings about copies and slices.

Keeping first line same as before,

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df["high"][i] > df["high"][i-1]:
        df.loc[i,"DaysHigh"] = df["DaysHigh"][i-1] + 1
    else:
        df.loc[i,"DaysHigh"] = 0
```

Comment: Hello ryl, thank you for the answer, 17-06-20 is 16 so it is bigger than the previous 8 row values. Your code not worked for me :( I think each row should be compared with the previous ones so another for or while maybe needed. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

procedure

1. Use pandas.shift() to create a column for the next row of comparison results.
2. calculate the cumulative sum of its created columns
3. delete the columns if they are not needed

```
df['tmp'] = np.where(df['high'] >= df['high'].shift(), 1, np.NaN)
df['dayshigh'] = df['tmp'].groupby(df['tmp'].isna().cumsum()).cumsum()
df.drop('tmp', axis=1, inplace=True)

df
    date    high    dayshigh
0   05-06-20    1.85    NaN
1   08-06-20    1.88    1.0
2   09-06-20    2.00    2.0
3   10-06-20    2.11    3.0
4   11-06-20    2.21    4.0
5   12-06-20    2.17    NaN
6   15-06-20    1.99    NaN
7   16-06-20    2.15    1.0
8   17-06-20    16.00   2.0
9   18-06-20    9.00    NaN
10  19-06-20    14.67   1.0
```

Comment: 17-06-20 dayshigh should be 8. Well my solution worked. Please check my answer. I used nested for loop. Do you know any built-in solution without for or while loops?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm resetting the cumulative sum in NaN, so only '17-06-20' is a row index that needs to be handled differently.